# What is the best way to scrape this webpage? fromJSON doesnt seem to work

Tags: json, r, web-scraping, jsonlite

I have been happily scraping parts of this mobile app website using getURL and fromJSON (jsonlite package in R). For example, I have been using this code and it is fairly straight forward:

```
CardURL = getURL("http://m.racingpost.com/#cards-horse/horse_id=901690& race_id=639116&r_date=2015-12-07")
CardDATA = fromJSON(CardURL)
CardDATA[["tab-card"]][["runners"]]
```

However when i got to this particular part of the webpage it doesn't work in same way as other sections:

```
http://m.racingpost.com/#cards-horse/horse_id=901690&race_id=639116&r_date=2015-12-07
```

It seems to return with text like 'your browzer isn't optimised' rather than returning the actual text I want to scrape. What is the best way to scrape data like this?

thanks

Comment: Just wondering if it is allowed to scrape data from this website.

Comment: webpages can stop you scraping data - is that possible?

Comment: Webpage, no. Privacy and terms, yes.